# NgRx shared store resets when loading lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx

I have various store modules that are imported to the main store module and each store module registers itself with `StoreModule.forFeature`. I also have various feature modules. I am trying to lazy load one of those feature modules but once it's loaded, the store gets reset. I don't want to lazy load any store modules. The whole store is shared. NgRx devTools lose all the previous actions and `@ngrx/store/init` and `@ngrx/effects/init` is re-run once the lazy loaded module is created. Any ideas how to keep the whole store intact once a lazy module is loaded?

**--- update ---**

**file structure**

```
store
 - store.module.ts
 - auth-store
   - actions.ts
   - effects.ts
   - reducer.ts
   - selectors.ts
   - state.ts
   - auth-store.module.ts
 - customers-store
   - ...
   - customers-store.module.ts
```

**auth-store.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('auth', authReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AuthEffects])
  ],
  providers: [AuthEffects]
})
export class AuthStoreModule {}
```

... same for `customers-store.module` and other store modules

**store.module**

```
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
       AuthStoreModule,
       CustomersStoreModule,
       ...
       StoreModule.forRoot({}),
       StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({ stateKey: 'router' }),
       EffectsModule.forRoot([])
      ]})
export class StoreModule {}
```

file structure for feature modules

```
app
 ui-components
   ....
   - header.component.ts
   - ui-components.module.ts
 dashboard
   .... 
   - dashboard.module.ts
 customers (lazy loaded)
   ....
   - customers-routing.module.ts
   - customers.module.ts
 router
   ....
  - router.module.ts
```

**customers-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ ... ]
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CustomersRoutingModule { }
```

**customers.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  .... ,
  CustomersRoutingModule
]})
export class CustomersModule { }
```

**router.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: '../customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
 {
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/dashboard',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 },
  ....
 ]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: false
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRouterModule { }
```

The `header.component.ts` (and the whole `ui-components` module) is shared among the lazy loaded customers component and the dashboard component. When I navigate to dashboard the `header.component` loads the user information located in `AuthStore`.
When I navigate to the lazy-loaded customers component the customers are retrieved correctly in the `customersStore`, the auth effects and reducers run but it seems they are on a different scope somehow. Thus the `header.component` never retrieves the user object but the `customers.component` retrieves the customers collection correctly. In redux devTools the store is cleared and only the actions that originate from the lazy-loaded component are shown. The actions from the common component are never shown (but the code is run nonetheless).

Comment: we need to see some code here mate

Comment: make sure every reducer returns state

Comment: @timdeschryver yes the reducers work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I imported my SharedStoreModule to the other modules. This caused the to spawn a new instance of the store once the lazy-loaded module was loaded. I removed all references to the SharedStoredModule and kept it only at the appModule level and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do all of your reducers contain a `default` case that simply returns the state?

If not then this might the the cause of your problem reducers that are called not returning state as @timdeschryver commented above sound like the most likely cause of this issue.

Comment: Problem was that I imported my sharedStoreModule to the other modules and it spawned a new instance.